# I'm having trouble getting my computer to save (multi) display settings

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, display-settings

Dell 7010
Win XP SP3
NVIDIA Force 210 graphics card
2 monitors

My sporadic problem:
I have 2 monitors with my display set up as an extended desktop (horizontal span).
Every once in a while when I boot up my pc my settings will revert to "clone". This is where both monitors display the exact same thing. This does not work with the applications that this particular pc is set up for. I must have it consistently boot up with a horizontal span extended desktop.

My theory:
One of the monitors is not turning on fast enough for the system to recognize it and it's switching the display mode to some sort of default.

Question:
Is there any way to change this so that it automatically defaults to a horizontal extended desktop?

Any other suggestions/ideas/theories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DisplayFusion to save the extended mode as a Monitor Profile, and then load it automatically on startup.

Info on Monitor Profiles here: http://www.displayfusion.com/KB/MonitorProfiles/

Info on setting a Monitor Profile on startup here: http://www.displayfusion.com/KB/LoadMonitorProfileOnStartup/

Disclosure: I do support and testing at Binary Fortress Software (makers of DisplayFusion) :)